# use of Jquery .after() for moving an element around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I'm reading the [jquery manual](http://api.jquery.com/after/) regarding the `.after()` function:

```
$('.container').after($('h2'));
```

and it says

> "If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be
>   moved rather than cloned"

So if I have multiple 
`<div class='before' onclick='afterfunction();'><div>`,

and I would want to place `<div class='after'></div>` after whichever div is clicked (have it move, not clone) would I do something like this?

```
var afterdiv = "<div class='after'></div>";
function afterfunction() {
    $(this).after(afterdiv);
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: `afterdiv` is not yet a DOM element. It's still in it's childhood: *a string*. :)

Comment: Listen to @RokoC.Buljan hes answering questions in comments like a BAUCE! (but yeah seriously hes right).

Comment: +1 to your question. Interesting and tricky the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said:

> **An element in the DOM can also be selected and inserted after another element:**
> $('.container').after($('h2'));
> If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere,
> it will be moved rather than cloned:

But you missed the bold part.

```
$('.before').click(function() {
  afterfunction(this);
});

// this will not work cause you'll append a string to your DOM
// var afterdiv = "<div class='after'>ola</div>";
// and will repeatedly be appended after each action.

// instead define your element by wrapping it into a $( )
  var afterdiv = $("<div class='after'>ola</div>");
// now 'afterdiv' variable is binded to that element only once inside the DOM 

function afterfunction(elem) {
   $(elem).after(afterdiv);
}
```

And you don't need to `.remove()` it (like wrongly suggested in an answer here.)

### *[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSncw/)*

Comment: You are absolutely correct and used the exact method i was trying to implement from the jquery website. Thanks !!

Comment: @iight A proof of concept is that if we change the DIV text like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NSncw/1/ you'll see the element is binded to that one, (I mean, there will not jump a new 'ola' texted DIV) after we repeat our earlier actions.

Answer (score 1):

Make `.before` div like this:

```
<div class='before'><div/>
```

Then try,

```
$('.before').on('click', function() {
  afterfunction(this);
});

function afterfunction(el) {
  var afterdiv = "<div class='after'></div>";
  $('.after').remove(); // remove previous `.after`
  $(el).after(afterdiv); // add newly after the clicked div
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/cSyjs/10/)**

Comment: This seems to create a new div each time :/
I'll make a jsfiddle to show you what I'm doing

Comment: "If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved rather than cloned" <-- I would like to do this, as it says in my question. Not to keep copying the div.

Comment: This will create a new `afterdiv` for each click. he wants only one afterdiv. Also, there is no need for `$(afterdiv)`, `.after()` can take an html string.

Comment: sorry to do this, but @Roko C. Buljan answer more correctly answers my question